# Create a new variable calculating expiry date from two other variables

Tags: c#

I have two variables:

EffectiveDate (Format comes out as 3/20/2025 12:00:00 AM)
ContractLength (Text e.g. 12 for 12 months

I want to take these variables values and calculate expiry date, so I guess EffectiveDate + 12 months so that I can build a report to say x contracts expiring within 30/60/90 days.

Need to do it in c#

So far I have this - seems to not really be doing the job though:

```
var startDateString = _context.Variables["EffectiveDate"].Value.ToString(); 
var contractTermString =  _context.Variables["ContractLength"].Value.ToString();
var contractTerm = int.Parse(contractTermString);
var startDate = System.DateTime.Parse(startDateString);
var expirationDate = startDate.AddMonths(contractTerm);
return expirationDate;
```

Am I doing something slightly wrong or am I close?

Thanks for looking!

Comment: **so I guess EffectiveDate + 12 months** first be sure of what you need, then ask it

Comment: What type is `EffectiveDate`?

Comment: What type is `_context.Variables["EffectiveDate"].Value` i.e. without the `ToString()`?

Comment: It's DateTime type

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: If EffectiveDate is a DateTime, why are you converting it to a string and then parsing it back to a DateTime? And when you say this is "not doing the job" - in what way? It seems to be doing what you say you want.